# Odd behaviour of the by() function in R 3.0.0?

Tags: r

I am trying to become familiar with the vast universe that constitutes R. There is an excellent function by() which seems to do just what I need, but it doesn't seem to like selection of multiple columns in a data frame.

I used the standard iris dataset, and while it seems well-behaved with a single column selected, it doesn't seem to like the selection of multiple columns. The example is taken from a reference book, but of course there may be a typo.

First version (this works)

```
> by(iris[,2],Species,mean)
Species: setosa
[1] 3.428
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Species: versicolor
[1] 2.77
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Species: virginica
[1] 2.974
```

Second version (this doesn't)

```
> by(iris[,2:3],Species,mean)
Species: setosa
[1] NA
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Species: versicolor
[1] NA
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Species: virginica
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
```

Any explanations gratefully received.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message you are getting is not related to the `by` function but rather to `mean`.
You passed it a `data.frame` when `mean` is expecting a vector.

If instead you were to use a function that work on `data.frame`s, then no warnings are thrown:

```
by(iris[,2:3],iris$Species, colMeans)
by(iris[,2:3],iris$Species, print)
etc
```

If you need to, you can nest `*ply` type functions (eg `by`, `tapply`, `lapply`, etc). 
Try this for example:

```
by(iris[,2:3],iris$Species,lapply, mean)
```

#### As for `mean`:

Notice that if you tried to call `mean` on any data.frame, it would complain:

```
mean(iris[,2:3])
mean(iris[iris$Species==iris$Species[[1]] ,2:3])
```

Use `colMeans` instead

```
colMeans(iris[iris$Species==iris$Species[[1]] ,2:3])
```

---

On an unrelated note:  Avoid using `attach`  ;)