# R - 'by' and 'mean' function

Tags: r

Here is the data: [Brain Size and Intelligence](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/DASL/Datafiles/Brainsize.html), I saved it as brainsize.txt. Then I typed:

```
brain = read.table('brainsize.txt', header = TRUE)
```

Now I typed:

```
by(data = brain[, -1], I = brain$Gender, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The output is:

```
In mean.default(brain$weight, na.rm = T) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

What's wrong here? I guess there are some changes happen to either the **by** function or **mean** function from R version **2.15** to **3.0.2**.

Answer (score 2):

¥ is not a number which is most likely making all your columns character. You could try

```
brain <- read.table('brainsize.txt', header = TRUE, na.string = "¥")
```

or change them to NA afterwards. Also do an `str(brain)` to make sure the columns you want the mean of are actually numeric or integer.

Comment: Could also use `..., colClasses=c("character", rep("numeric",6))  )`

Comment: Actually R has automatically changed ¥ to NA. So, that's not the problem.

Comment: Well, ...  an experienced R user would have expected it to cause the column to be of class factor (as happens on my machine) and to throw the error you got if you tried to take mean of a factor

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the answer is here: [Odd behaviour of the by() function in R 3.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325399/odd-behaviour-of-the-by-function-in-r-3-0-0?rq=1)

**mean** simply does not work with **data.frame**. Rather, **lapply** (or any other *ply) shuold be used then pass the function **mean**.

```
by(data = brain[, -1], I = brain$Gender, FUN = lapply, mean,  na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I think that is an insufficiently detailed description. It does not address the error that would have occurred in the input phase, although it might have fixed the error in trying to take mean of the subset dataframe.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Could you elaborate your comment?

Comment: There were two columns that would under ordinary circumstances be factor class if input with the code in your question. If you changed the input code to fix that problem, then you should have posted it in either your question or your answer. (You also posted no successful code, hence my negative vote.)